# Методологии проектирования пользовательских интерфейсов

Tags: gui, веб-программирование

Здравствуйте, уважаемые форумчане. Подскажите, пожалуйста, существуют ли стандарты (методологии, диаграммы и т.д.), с помощью которых можно проектировать элементы пользовательского интерфейса?

Поясню на примере.
Предположим, мне необходимо разработать макет некоторого сайта (для краткости буду называть его site.ru).
Я создаю макет главной страницы (например, в MS Visio) и отмечаю на нем некоторые элементы, например, кнопку регистрации. Мне необходимо на схеме отобразить операции, которые будут осуществляться при клике на данную кнопку.

Пусть, при клике на кнопку, выполняются следующие операции:

1. Отображается всплывающее окно с полями "Имя", "E-mail", "Пароль" и кнопкой "Отправить".
2. При заполнении полей из п.1 и клике на кнопку "Отправить" отображается сообщение "На ваш e-mail отправлено сообщение с сылкой для подтверждения регистрации".

Подводя итог.
Существуют ли какие-нибудь общепринятые стандарты, позволяющие схематично описывать возможные действия пользователя с тем или иным элементом интерфейса, а также результаты этих действий?

Аналогия.
В разработке программного обеспечения есть язык UML. С помощью него можно схематично отображать элементы (не путайте с элементами пользовательского интерфейса) разрабатываемой программы. В качестве наглядного примера привожу скрин диаграммы активности:

[image]

Хотелось бы найти похожую аналогию для элементов пользовательского интерфейса.

P.S.
Программы Axure и ей подобные не подходят. Так как, описание поведения необходимо прикреплять к техническому заданию.

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: [Тут есть книга](http://www.uxpin.com/knowledge.html) "The Guide to UX Design Process & Documentation". Не читал. Попалась на глаза, вспомнил ваш вопрос. ([Прямая ссылка](https://s3.amazonaws.com/uxpin/uxpin_guide_to_uxdesign_process_and_documentation.zip), чтобы не регистрироваться)

Comment: @Sergiks спасибо за книгу. Она содержит очень полезный материал по организации рабочего процесса в дизайн студии (порекомендовал, друзьям, работающим в этой области). Но, к сожалению, именно мою проблему не решила. Но все равно, спасибо Вам.

Answer (score 1):

Для описания работы интерфейса можно использовать нотацию eEPC, либо тот же uml - use-case либо диаграмма деятельности.